# How to resize a console window using the Windows API?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I have a simple piece of demo code that draws a yellow pixel to coordinates (100,100) in the console. I was wondering, can I modify the screen's dimensions so that I could have variables such as: `int WIDTH = 1000; int HEIGHT = 1000` and make the console conform to these dimensions?

```c
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //Get a console handle
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    //Get a handle to device context
    HDC dc = GetDC(console);

    //Choose any color
    COLORREF COLOR= RGB(255,255,255); 

    SetPixel(dc,100,100,COLOR);

    ReleaseDC(console, dc);
}
```

Comment: The Windows console functions are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). Among them are `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` and `SetConsoleWindowInfo`.

Comment: It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve. The console is a text device, but then you are using the GDI to render graphics. You can apply [coordinate space transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/coordinate-spaces-and-transformations) to device contexts. But I wonder how that ties back to your use of the console. What's the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1):

As @WeatherVane pointed out and [Scrolling the Screen Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-the-screen-buffer) explained:

> The console window displays a portion of the active screen buffer.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/images/cscon-01.png]

The picture comes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/images/cscon-01.png.

Your pixel coordinate should be in the console screen buffer, which can be modified by [SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbufferinfoex) and then you use [SetConsoleWindowInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) to set the current size and position of a console screen buffer's window.
Tested using [Scrolling a Screen Buffer's Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/scrolling-a-screen-buffer-s-window) with a little change.

[image]

Comment: Apart from console input and console output, [the console screen buffer is a two-dimensional array of character and color data for output in a console window and A number of properties associated with a screen buffer can be set independently for each screen buffer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers) for example Window size and location, Cursor position, appearance, and visibility, etc. @Saw